# how can i transfer my project from github repository to aws server? which type of aws services(ec2 or s3) i can use to do so?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github

I have already created an instance in ec2 and connected to the ssh

how can I transfer my project from GitHub repository to AWS server? which type of AWS services(ec2 or s3)  i can use to do so??

Answer (score 0):

In the GitHub web UI, find the big green "Code" button
and click on Code --> Download ZIP.

Use `scp` to transfer it to your ec2 instance.

Or use the amazon web console to upload the .zip to an S3 bucket.
Or install CLI tools and use

```
$ aws s3 sync myproject.zip s3://mybucket/
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say use the git clone command for your project and if your unable to create a key you can use git clone with the ssh option - which is the same but requires you to put password for every pull or push
Regarding the instance if your deploying a application you should use the EC2 instance where as S3 instance is more often used for storing objects such as image files or other type of files but to run actual code you should use EC2

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by using the `git clone` command.

Login to your `ec-2` instance via `ssh`.

```
ssh -i "/path/to/pem/file.pem" remote-name@ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.us-xxxx-x.compute.amazonaws.com
```

After logging in, run the following:

```
git clone <link to repo>
```

Please note that the link to repository is made available once you click on the `Code` button on your repo page.

The other way of doing this, i.e., downloading the repo and then uploading it to your `ec-2` instance via `scp` is inefficient. The secure copy (`scp`) is only good if you want to copy a project that resides in your local machine. Otherewise, there seems no purpose of first downloading and then uploading the whole project.

Also, I would not recommend putting your code base on `s3`, as it is not made for this purpose. It is better if your project resides in `ec-2`. If you want that your environment persists when your stop and again start your instance, then use `ebs` instead.